# Twitter Bootstrap collapsing menu not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

I am a bit lost here, mainly because I don't know jquery but I am trying to uses bootstraps collapsing jquery plugin to get a mobile first menu working. I am not using bootstraps css, do I need to be using it? is it possible to just use the jquery plugin without any of bootstraps  css? When I press the three bar menu icon nothing happens. My css is currently hiding and revealing the three bar menu icon—I don't know if this is competing with whatever is in the jquery or not.

```
<body>  
    <section class="grid sticky">
        <div class="container"> 
            <header class="grid twelve header">
                <a href="#" class="menuButton btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <div class="iconBar"></div>
                    <div class="iconBar"></div>
                    <div class="iconBar"></div>
                </a>
                <div class="logoHolder">
                    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo/ks_logo.svg"> 
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Main Nav, hidden below 768 px -->

                <nav class="mainNav not-phone not-phoneSM">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>  
    </section>
    <!-- Mobile Main Nav, called upon to relieve when screen is at 768 px -->
    <section class="not-desktop not-tablet">
            <header>
                <nav class="mobileMainNav nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
    </section>


    <!-- jQuery via Google + local fallback, see h5bp.com -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Bootstrap jQuery Plugins, compiled and minified -->
    <script src="bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: <!-- jQuery via Google + local fallback, see h5bp.com -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Bootstrap jQuery Plugins, compiled and minified -->
<script src="bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
 </body>

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="bootstrap2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: above are the two scripts I am using at the bottom of my html doc

Comment: I am not sure what you did?

Comment: I just fixed up the way some of your code was showing. Maybe you could set up a jsfiddle for this with your css etc so we can what you are trying to achieve a little better?

Comment: ok, I can do that but what exactly is a jsfiddle?

Comment: It's a website for testing / prototyping / showing off / and generally fiddling with html, js, and css. I've started one here, maybe you could add to it? http://jsfiddle.net/FdDHC/

Comment: @Ken can you please check my answer

Comment: wow that is cool, im sure but do i need to set up an account before being able to share code with you on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy there are Style classes in css files of bootstrap which are used by dropdown js to work .
 So either you write your custom styles for them or use the default styles . There are few I am mentioning below:

```
    .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {

       }
     .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before {

          }
     .dropdown-menu > li > a {

         }
     .dropdown-menu{

         }
     .dropdown-toggle {
     }
    .dropdown{
          }
```

Stick the `dropdown` class to the Li element you want to have dropdown toggle functionality.

And to the attach `dropdown-menu` to the `ul` to display dropdown menu .

Example :

```
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Hom <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
                      </ul>

        </li>
 </ul>
```

You can completely rewrite these styles and use them in your project .

Comment: ohh ok, I know very little about jquery and I wasn't sure if the plugin was just calling stuff from the html.

Comment: You can customize the classes and use them according to your needs

Answer (score -1):

i think you need add at the end

```
<script src="bootstrap2/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

the source of http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js

Comment: i placed the dropdown.js at the end but unfortunately didn't work. the three bar menu icon doesn't reveal the menu.

Comment: He has the full bootstrap.min.js included.